# Chrome app Picasa identity: OAuth2 request failed: Service responded with error: 'bad client id: {0}'

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-oauth, google-chrome-app, picasa

I'm trying to authorize with chrome.identity.getAuthToken() to get token for Picasa web service. I couldn't find Picasa API in Google Developer Console and set its scope to "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/" oauth2 part of manifest.json. [Picasa docs](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Auth) say that I can skip this step.

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
    interactive: true
}, function (token) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    } else {
        console.log(token);
    }
});
```

getAuthToken() always ends with an error "OAuth2 request failed: Service responded with error: 'bad client id: {0}'". If no scopes are set, the error looks like "OAuth2 request failed". Where have I mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems amazing but after 1 day has passed, everything is working :)

UPD: I've tried gdrive sample from [chrome-app-samples](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples) repo and added scope for Picasa. After everything worked fine, I copied its key and oauth2 section to my app's manifest. Everything worked fine too. After this I deleted client_id for app in developer console and created it again. And after that everything was ok.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @keshlam as you can see there were no helpful answers here.

Comment: @AJ just updated my thoughts to be more helpful to the next SO users facing this problem.

Answer (score 9):

Steps I take to make it work

1. Go to [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) and create a new project.
2. Go to **APIs & auth** > **Credentials** in the panel to create new Client ID. The application ID of chrome app can be obtained from [Chrome Developer Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard) if you your app is uploaded.
3. Go to **APIs & auth** > **Consent screen** and fill in Email Address and Product Name and Save.

I didn't know step 3 was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your application in Google Developer Console and obtain a client_id. See the 'Credentials' pane to configure your application.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my project credentials look like this: http://d.pr/i/Km7H