# Error 'Service has been disabled for this account' while running identity.getAuthToken for chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-oauth

I am trying to create an extension that uses the selected data and saves it to google sheets. Sounds pretty simple though but I am stuck at the Auth2 part.

Here's what I have done so far:

I have created a `manifest.json` and uploaded it on the chrome developer dashboard to obtain the "key" and "id".

Used the "id" to get the auth client id and added it to my `manifest.json`.

Next I have added basic html in "popup.html" and the context menu code part in "options.js" which is defined as the background script in "manifest.json".

Next I am using the "getAuthToken " to get the token in "popup.js". When I run the extension everything works but once I click the button to get the token nothing happens and "undefined" token value is returned.The error message is

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running identity.getAuthToken: OAuth2 request failed: Service responded with error: 'Service has been disabled for this account.'

#### Manifest.json

```
{
"name":"ext1",
"manifest_version":2,
"version": "1.0",
"description":"",
"browser_action":{
    "default_icon":"icon48.png",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
},

"permissions":[
"identity",
"https://*/*",
"http://*/*",
"contextMenus",
"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
"storage"
],
"background":{
    "scripts":["options.js"],
    "persistent":false
    },
"content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com; object-src 'self'",
"oauth2":{
    "client_id":"<>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes":[
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
    ]
},
"key":"<>"}
```

#### Popup.html

```
 <!doctype <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>text</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<h1>random text</h1>
<h2> Data:  <span id="data"></span></h2>
<input type="submit" id="button" value="Authorize">
</body>
</html>
```

#### popup.js

```
$(function(){
    chrome.storage.sync.get('datas', function(values){
        $('#data').text(values.datas);
    })
    $("#button").on("click",function(){
        chrome.identity.getAuthToken({"interactive":true},function(token){
        alert("getting token......")  
        console.log("token")
        console.log(token);
        })
    })
})
```

I have tried searching for similar issues but none solves my issue. kindly help what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you resolved it? If yes then please share the solution.

Comment: full reboot helped.

Answer (score 2):

You may be using an account with Google [advanced protection](https://landing.google.com/advancedprotection/) which disables Gmail and Google Drive related API access for non-Google apps:

> To keep your data secure, most non-Google apps and services won’t be able to access some data in your Google Account, like Google Drive or Gmail. [*](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7539956#non-goog_apps)

Also see this announcement from Google: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/enhancing-security-controls-for-google-drive-third-party-apps

> Today we’re announcing plans to extend the same policy to Google Drive as part of Project Strobe.

> With this updated policy, we’ll limit the types of apps that have broad access to content or data via Drive APIs.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer with the suggestion in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662966/chrome-app-picasa-identity-oauth2-request-failed-service-responded-with-error) to make it work:

> 1. Go to [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) and create a new project.
> 2. Go to **APIs & auth > Credentials** in the panel to create new Client ID. The application ID of chrome app can be obtained from [Chrome Developer Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard) if your app is uploaded.
> 3. Go to **APIs & auth > Consent screen** and fill in Email Address and Product Name and Save.

Answer (score 0):

Using another Google Account to sign in have worked for me and fixed the issue.