# OAuth2 request failed: Connection failed (-2)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-oauth

**REPOST this question, just now was closed due to duplicate to the below question but that question is different to the questiont that I want to ask.*
*[Error 'Service has been disabled for this account' while running identity.getAuthToken for chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51578410/error-service-has-been-disabled-for-this-account-while-running-identity-getaut)**

I am building a chrome extension that using the Google API

When I am trying to run this code

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive :true},function(auth_token)
    {
        console.log(auth_token)
    })
```

I got this error message in my console.

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: OAuth2 request failed: Connection failed (-2).

May I know what is this error message's meaning?

I can't find any documentation regards to this error.

Comment: "but that question is different to the questiont that I want to ask"—how? Please read [ask].

Comment: @Chris yeah, maybe I have problem on "how to ask" but I can guarantee that that question can't help me to solve my question, because once you have look at the question , you will know he's facing of "Service has been disabled for this account", but for my question, I am facing of "Connection failed".

Comment: Maybe this question and that question also asking regarding to the OAuth2 and getAuthToken but these two questions are in different direction.

Comment: And then, why I am having "Connection Failed" is because of I am using Microsoft Edge than Google Chrome, and Edge disabled getAuthToken in their browser. From that question, I can't see any answer same as what I have mentioned. LOL